# What exactly is a 'token' in terms of java?

Tags: java, file, search, token

So I'm working on this program that opens all .java and .txt files in a specified directory, and does some analyzing on these files. One thing my program is supposed to find is the "Most frequently occurring token(s)" in each of the .txt and .java files. I only have a limited understanding of what qualifies as a token. Would a program that just finds the most common word in the file do the same thing? Or how do I go about specifying my method to find tokens, and not just words?

Any further explanation of what qualifies as a token is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In this context, I'd say it's just a uniquely identifiable string. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Token

Comment: This is a good opportunity to ask for clarification of this assignment. Since the meaning of token in this context could vary.

Answer (score 3):

A token is the smallest element that the Java Virtual Machine will recognize. It can include a word, keywords, numbers, special characters, operators, etc. A detailed article on the subject can be found here: https://www.quora.com/What-are-tokens-in-java

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the (assignment) is poorly specified. The concept of tokens has to do with parsing string input. Like, a calculator function can take in a string, break it up using *a set of separators*(often whitespace characters). The tokens, like operators and numbers, are the tokens. Depending on the type of input, the parser doesn’t have to use whitespace as separators. Another option could be punctuation, or tabs for tab-delimited text. The tokens are whatever exists between the separators. The parser function then processes the tokens.

So, a short answer to your question is:
 - words and punctuation marks for text files with human language, probably.
- if you are only parsing code, you have a decision to make. Are objects, properties, methods, and operators including the dot operator all supposed to be tokens, or does a token refer to one entity: (I.e.: is WordCounter.getTotals() one token or three? Or 5? These are judgement calls).

Comment: I see. Thanks for your response. Other parts of the assignment ask me to find "space-delineated tokens". Would this mean that spaces are what separate tokens. Like in that case, would WordCounter.getTotals() be considered one space-delineated token, assuming there are spaces on either side?

Comment: Yes. That's how I interpret "space-delineated tokens"